# leaf nodes jquery - how to write statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve a date from a webpage that is not embedded in any html tags and trying to inject this date into a div residing on another webpage.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#date-box").load("http://www.test.html b:last");
}); // end handler
```

I am able to retrieve the text wrapped inside bold element but not the text that appears next to this element. Any suggestions how how I can modify my JQuery selector is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

the html markup looks like,

```
<br>
<br>
<b>Last Edit Date:</b>
4/19/2017 4:23:40 PM
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: The date is still inside an element, probably the same that holds the `<b>` tag.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of www.test.html, we can't determine which selector wil load both.